# Vertical alignment of button with image icon on Firefox

Tags: css, flexbox

I just realised Firefox doesn't render a button with icon correctly. Because the icon is an image, I made the button flex (in real life an inline-flex). Given this basic markup:

```css
button {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 40px;
}
i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button><i></i>Label</button>
```

On the latest Chrome (v79) I see:

[image]

And on the latest Firefox (v72) I see:

[image]

Looks like a bug in Firefox. Any idea on how to fix it, or can I achieve the same thing without flexbox? Thanks!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nuthinking/pen/d64da8788475c1c9c09a869f7403156d?editors=1100)